# Running a Docker container with the -p or -P flag causes it to fail

Tags: web-applications, docker, port

I have recently started moving my simple blog app into a docker container. I created my own dockerfile and built the image successfully and it runs the webapp with no issues however if I add the -P or -p 8080:8080 flags to the run command it fails with error:

```
mathew@mathew-laptop:goblog:-> docker run -it -P chasinglogic/test
FATA[0002] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 0042e27ea10942b4b394b7179d8dc43e3996e28c773d400672fd2333833659ad:  (exit status 1)
```

I have CMD set to automatically run my executable and I have EXPOSE 8080 in my Dockerfile. I originally thought this must be an issue with my webapp not liking docker's port forwarding or with my Dockerfile so I went to the Docker tutorials and tested with the training/webapp image and got the same error:

```
mathew@mathew-laptop:goblog:-> sudo docker run -d -P training/webapp python app.py
[sudo] password for mathew: 
Unable to find image 'training/webapp:latest' locally
Pulling repository training/webapp
31fa814ba25a: Download complete 
511136ea3c5a: Download complete 
f10ebce2c0e1: Download complete 
82cdea7ab5b5: Download complete 
5dbd9cb5a02f: Download complete 
74fe38d11401: Download complete 
64523f641a05: Download complete 
0e2afc9aad6e: Download complete 
e8fc7643ceb1: Download complete 
733b0e3dbcee: Download complete 
a1feb043c441: Download complete 
e12923494f6a: Download complete 
a15f98c46748: Download complete 
Status: Downloaded newer image for training/webapp:latest
fac4cd8b43b984b14cbcc0567fe3b22801574e8a07069b401328afa9e20f3c97
FATA[0111] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container fac4cd8b43b984b14cbcc0567fe3b22801574e8a07069b401328afa9e20f3c97:  (exit status 1)
```

As soon as I remove the -p or -P flags the images run fine. I disabled my firewall to eliminate it as a possible source. I cannot find any documentation telling me what the FATA error codes mean so before I decide to start digging through Docker source code (OH GOD PLEASE NO) to find this stuff I was hoping someone on here had a better answer. I can provide any further info upon request.

Answer found:

instead of the port in dockerfile, what if you do this : docker run -p 127.0.0.1:$HOSTPORT:$CONTAINERPORT --name CONTAINER -t someimage –  purpletech

Thanks purpletech. As a note I did not change the Dockerfile at all just ran the command the way it is shown.

Comment: Do you already have other things running on 8080 ?

Comment: Nope checked that and even changed the port mapping to three different ports.

Comment: instead of the port in dockerfile, what if you do this : docker run -p 127.0.0.1:$HOSTPORT:$CONTAINERPORT --name CONTAINER -t someimage

Comment: What distribution, system version, and docker version?

Comment: Purpletech provided a working answer. Not sure why it works but it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glad it worked.
I suspected a a permission issues binding to non local host so adviced you to explicitly bind to localhost.

instead of the port in dockerfile, what if you do this : docker run -p 127.0.0.1:$HOSTPORT:$CONTAINERPORT --name CONTAINER -t someimage